# How to run same test multiple times using jest

Tags: node.js, jestjs

I am using jest to run my test suite (with back-end as Node.js & express). Below is my code:

```
const puppeteer = require ('puppeteer');

test('testing login function', async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch ({  
        headless: true,
        args: ['--no-sandbox']
  });

    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.type('#username', 'admin');
    await page.type('#password', 'password');

    await page.click('login-button');

    await page.waitFor('.card');

    expect(texthead).toEqual('Welcome to webpage');

    await browser.close();
});
```

I am trying to run this same test multiple times at once, is there a way using it by jest, or maybe using other tools.

Comment: Can you wrap the testing code in in a loop?

Comment: Yes, I tried for loop but it will run sequentially. I want  to run multiple tests at once.

Answer (score 33):

If you're looking for something that will essentially stress test a single test (looking for test flakiness like I was) then you could use the following one-liner in your terminal, which of course uses bash and Jest together.

```
for i in {1..100}; do npx jest <test_file> --silent || (echo "Failed after $i attempts" && break); done
```

This specific command requires you to have `npx` installed and it uses the `--silent` option but you can change it as you please.

Comment: A useful flag in `jest` for this case would be `-o` (instead of `<test_file>`). Run only modified/new tests that way you can have "Flakiness CI" on your tests.

Comment: When running this with a failing test, I get the following printed `Failed after $i attempts
bash: break: only meaningful in a `for', `while', or `until' loop`  and the loop doesn't break. An alternative is `for i in {1..100}; do npx jest <test_file> --silent; if [[ "$?" != 0 ]]; then echo "Failed after $i attempts" && break; fi; done` . The double quotes are needed to interpolate $i

Answer (score 10):

Jest has a built in method for this using `.each()`. https://jestjs.io/docs/api#testeachtablename-fn-timeout

If you want to change the parameters of each test, you can pass an array of test parameters to `.each([1,2,3])`. If this is un-necessary, just fill the array with null.

`test.each(Array(100).fill(null))('may be flaky test', async () => {})`

This can optionally be run in parallel using `.concurrent`
`test.concurrent.each(Array(100).fill(null))('may be flaky test', async () => {})`

Answer (score 6):

If you don't want tests run sequentially, you can use `Promise.all`. Here is a quick example of how you could refactor your code.

```
const runTheTest = async () => { 
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch ({
    headless: true, args: ['--no-sandbox'] 
  });
  .......
  return browser.close();
}

test('testing login function', async () => { 
  const testRuns = []
  for (let index = 0; index < NUMBER_OF_RUNS; index++) {
    testRuns.push(runTheTest())
  }
  return Promise.all(testRuns);
})
```

Answer (score 3):

`npx` installed packages over and over and I wanted to time if my change improved the test speed. It's not great, but what I did was putting a command in the `package.json`

```
"jest": "jest <file_path> --silent"
```

and then borrowed the script from Brady as

```
for i in {1..100}; do yarn jest || (echo 'Failed after $i attempts' && break); done
```

I wrapped it in a timer, but that's not necessary really.